# How to launch an AWS Lambda Function locally on my computer?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

Our development team has created several AWS Lambdas Functions written in Java that are currently running on the cloud.

I have imported them locally on my computers.

They are all Maven projects.

I have already installed both the JDK and Maven.

I do not know what is the next step for launching them locally.

Is there any client that I should install before?

Comment: Lambda function handlers have a very specific interface. If you want to test them locally then you would typically use project tooling such as AWS SAM or Serverless Framework. If you simply want to wrap the Lambda function code in some-custom written wrapper so that you can run them locally then you can do that, but you'd have to write code to invoke the Lambda function handler, providing the relevant context and event parameters.

Comment: @jarmod where can I find the documentation to do it?

Comment: There's no specific documentation. This isn't a supported path (from a cloud deployment backwards to an on-prem dev environment). But it should be possible. If these Lambda functions are deployed as Docker container images then you may be in better shape. You'll need to understand how your Lambda functions are structured, what their expected inputs are (context and event), and then provide a Java wrapper for them to run locally. You might also find that they have been written with dependencies on the Lambda runtime environment, e.g. the presence of of `/tmp` directory, so account for that.

Comment: @jarmod rewrite your answer. I am going to give you the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda function handlers have a very specific interface, typically with event and context parameters. The shape of the event parameter depends on the source of the event that triggered the Lambda function (here's an [SQS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)).

If you want to test a Lambda function locally then you would typically start from a local development environment that uses project tooling such as AWS SAM or Serverless Framework. Those tools typically support some way of configuring events and invoking a Lambda function locally with those events. This allows local development, debugging, and testing.

If you can't use one of those tools, then you can typically simply wrap your Lambda function code in some custom-written wrapper code so that you can run it locally, but you'd have to write code to invoke the Lambda function handler, providing the relevant event and context parameters. Typically the context parameter is not all that important for local development.

Unfortunately, there's no specific documentation for this path (taking a native Lambda function and moving it to a local development environment). This isn't a supported path (from a cloud deployment backwards to an on-prem dev environment), but it should be possible. If these Lambda functions are deployed as Docker container images then you may be in better shape.

You'll need to understand how your Lambda functions are structured, what their expected inputs are (context and event), and then provide a Java wrapper for them to run locally. You might also find that they have been written with dependencies on the Lambda runtime environment, e.g. the presence of `/tmp` directory or specific environment variables or an IAM role with specific IAM permissions, so account for that when attempting to run locally.

So, I think you can do this but it's not trivial. It's generally a better path to start from local using SAM or Serverless, however with some effort you might also be able to retrofit your Lambda functions into that local tooling.